# Kstream how it manage joins and topic expiration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need ask a question to get some clarification.

Let's assume this scenario: topic1 and topic2 are 2 tables of same database, table1 have a high amount of updates/insert, table2 is standard almost never updated. Let's assume also that we have a streaming that join the 2 tables

After 3-6 months what will happen to the join of the 2 tables? 
What i am expecting is that at a certain time Kafka will empty topic2 because there are no updates so I think that the join wil always return null

how kafka will manage this kind of situation?

Comment: The join window would need adjusted to capture all events needing joined, but the Kafka topic itself has its own retention policies, so if you don't want deleted messages, maybe increase the retention? Kafka doesn't "manage" if data comes from external systems, or not, so this seems very specific to be implemented within some Kafka Streams logic (or don't use Streams, and use Connect to sink data from individual topics into a separate system where you will join events)

Comment: You should use log compacted topics instead of retention based topics.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax can you provide me more details about this?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction